# Fuzzy logic vs AI vs Machine learning vs Deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, fuzzy-logic

How do these four subjects differ from one another? From what I understand, they learn from numerous input data and output an estimated output. My understanding is very lacking thus me questioning these. It made no sense to me about the examples given by people such as the spam email, apple orange cat dog identification, neural network examples.

Is there a better representation of these four subjects in a more simpler example with coding to show the concept? I really appreciate that a lot.

Links to example you think that is very simple with code is more than welcome. I need something relate-able to get the code writing concept better.

Many thanks!

Comment: looks like a Quora not SO type of question :)

Comment: This is way too broad of a question, and not really on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Okay. I thought as long as coding is involved, SO is the choice ><

Comment: I think this should be on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/. But I don't think it is too broad (see my answer)

Comment: @iHateUni Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't, and take a look at [ask]. I would also like to tell you that it is important to show research effort in your question. The way your question is now it seems very much as if you just read those terms somewhere and immediately came over here to ask about them instead of researching those terms by yourself first. Also, questions about explaining AI terminology might fit better on http://ai.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 10):

> [Fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) is a form of many-valued logic in which the truth values of variables may be any real number between 0 and 1. By contrast, in Boolean logic, the truth values of variables may only be the integer values 0 or 1. Fuzzy logic has been employed to handle the concept of partial truth, where the truth value may range between completely true and completely false.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbSmP.png) Furthermore, when linguistic variables are used, these degrees may be managed by specific (membership) functions.
>
> The field of [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) research defines itself as the study of "intelligent agents": any device that perceives its environment and takes actions that maximize its chance of success at some goal. Colloquially, the term "artificial intelligence" is applied when a machine mimics "cognitive" functions that humans associate with other human minds, such as "learning" and "problem solving" (known as Machine Learning).

Machine Learning by Tom Mitchell:

> A computer program is said to learn from experience E with respect to some class of tasks T and performance measure P if its performance at tasks in T, as measured by P, improves with experience E.

Deep learning is machine learning with deep neural networks.

Hence: AI is a superset of Machine Learning. Machine Learning is a superset of Deep learning. AI includes fuzzy logic:

[image]

### Resources

- [Fuzzy logic lecture notes](https://martin-thoma.com/informationsfusion/#fuzzy-systeme) (German)
- Computerphile: [Fuzzy logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r804UF8Ia4c)
- IEEE: [Fuzzy logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8wY6mi1vV8)
- Tom Mitchel: [Machine Learning](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/mlbook.html)
- Michael Nielsen: [Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/)